# Is it possible to create a video from a Javascript animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a web app that plays an animation using javascript, html, css. Is there a way that I can record that to a video file so that a user can download and view the animation without going to the site?

Comment: No, in short...

Comment: @seesharper [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)?

Comment: @ChrisHappy ha! Live and learn :)

Comment: iOS can record your screen, buttons need to be added to your dashboard https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207935

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, using [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) and [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var video = document.querySelector("video");

var colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "black", "white", "green"];
function draw (){
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
draw();

var videoStream = canvas.captureStream(30);
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(videoStream);

var chunks = [];
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
  chunks.push(e.data);
};

mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
  var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' });
  chunks = [];
  var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  video.src = videoURL;
};
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
  chunks.push(e.data);
};

mediaRecorder.start();
setInterval(draw, 300);
setTimeout(function (){ mediaRecorder.stop(); }, 5000);
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<p>Wait for 5 seconds...</p>
<video autoplay controls download></video>
```

Source: [How to record a canvas element by
Alexis Delrieu](https://medium.com/@amatewasu/how-to-record-a-canvas-element-d4d0826d3591)

**Note**: At the time of writing, ~95% of global users can use MediaRecorder according to [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/mediarecorder).

Comment: Keep in mind not all browsers support this: [Can I use?](https://caniuse.com/mediarecorder)

Comment: The answer already has that, and around 75% of users can use it, which is a good score!